# Can I combine all HTTP headers?

Tags: http-headers

On some pages I redirect my clients with a "303 See Other" status header.

We also decided we do not want bots to examine the site. If I write the "X-Robots-Tag: none" as first header on ALL pages, could this cause problems when "303 See Other" status header is written as second header?

Or generally asked: Which HTTP headers must not be combined?

I was searching for some RFC, but couldn't find one. Any hint is highly appreciated.